# Jasmine Test Fails - But log suggests otherwise

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

This test is throwing the error `Expected spy phone to have been called.` - the mock class method is being called as demonstrated by the `log` in the terminal. The mock class is not being called by any other tests. I assume I am missing something simple here, but I am not sure why `formatSpy` in the test is failing.

**My Provider in TestBed.ConfigureTestingModule:**

```
        {provide: FormatService, useClass: FormatServiceMock},
```

**My Mock Class:**

```
        export class FormatServiceMock {
             phone() {
               console.log('format phone');
               return;
            }
       }
```

**My Function Being Tested:**

```
    public getPhone(): string {
        if (this.data && this.data.settings) {
            return this.format.phone(this.data.settings.phone);
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
```

**My Test:**

```
        it('should call format service', () => {
            service.data = data;
            service.getPhone();
            let formatSpy = spyOn(format, 'phone').and.callThrough();
            expect(formatSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

**My Output:**

```
LOG: 'format phone'
HeadlessChrome 79.0.3945 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 28 of 87 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1.477 secs)
LOG: 'format phone'
HeadlessChrome 79.0.3945 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) EnvironmentService getPhone should call format service FAILED
    Expected spy phone to have been called.
```

**UPDATE**
changing MOCK to:

```
export class FormatServiceMock {
    phone(phone) {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

and TEST to:

```
     it('should call format service', () => {
         service.data = data;
         let result = service.getPhone();
         let formatSpy = spyOn(format, 'phone').and.callThrough();
         expect(result).toEqual('5553335555'); //<--- PASSES
         expect(formatSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <---- FAILS
     })
```

With my hack around I can remove `expect(formatSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()` and know that the function works as expected - but its still a mystery to me why my spy fails when everything executes as expected.

Comment: I assume, `format` refers to `FormatService`. Try `expect(format.phone).toHaveBeenCalled();` as the assertion.

Comment: @AliF50 it outputs the same error `Expected spy phone to have been called.`
 - I wonder if it could be some kind of local caching issue, since I assumed a different error message in this scenario?

Comment: Maybe the `callThrough()` is actually calling it (not sure). Try removing the `callThrough`, we don't need to actually call the method, we just need to know whether it was called or not. In the `if` block of `getPhone()` put a console.log of ('In the if block !!!!') and see if it gets logged. If it doesn't, that means the method was not called.

Comment: I am passing the conditional in `getPhone()` - here is the log ```LOG: 'inside getPhone', Object{settings: Object{phone: '5553335555'}}
LOG: 'format phone'``` - is the object thats passed in somehow failing it out maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spyOn function needs to be called **before** your code calls the spied upon function

This should fix it :

```
let formatSpy = spyOn(format, 'phone').and.callThrough();
service.getPhone();
expect(formatSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Bah - so simple I should have caught that - thanks!!